# How to add in router vue.js one word exception in the path in one route?

Tags: vue.js

I have a path like this:  `path: '/:id` in the route. How to exclude from this path one word that can come?  I tried `\b(?:(?!word)\w)+\b`, in regex101 it's work, but when I add it to this path like this `path: '/:id(\\b(?:(?!word)\\w)+\\b)'`nothing works at all. Help...

`if (!getToken()) { routerMap.push({ path: '/', component: Layout, children: [ { path: '/:identifier, name: 'CMSPage', component: () => import('@/views/cms/page'), props: true, }, ], }) }`

Comment: Why do you want to exclude that one `word` ?

Comment: `word` is for example. There is another word. Want to exclude, because if it come to the route, then redirecting is going to the wrong place.

Comment: What are your routes? Please give us some examples of the possible routes.

Answer (score 0):

If you try your path definition in [express-route-tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/) (link found on [Path-to-RegExp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0) - library used by Vue Router to match routes) you will see it matches only one letter

- you need to move `+` inside (`/:identifier(\\b(?:(?!word)\\w+)\\b)`)
- and still this will not match for example `wordss`

Result: `/:identifier(\b(?:(?!word\b)\w+)\b)`

But maybe you are trying to solve something with regex what can be solved different way ? Do you know the Vue Router takes routes in order ? So if you define two routes:

```
/word
/:id
```

First will take precedence...

Comment: Here is the route ` if (!getToken()) {
  routerMap.push({
    path: '/',
    component: Layout,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/:identifier',
        name: 'CMSPage',
        component: () => import('@/views/cms/page'),
        props: true,
      },
    ],
  })
}` I want to add to path rules like this `/:identifier(\b(?:(?!notifications\b)\w+)\b)` . But if I add it, nothing works at all. Something like this...

Comment: That's not enough. Sorry but with so little info I have nothing to add to my answer...